# Admob slows down my game - LIBGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have my game perfectly optimized. Doesn't go bellow 61-60 FPS. When I finish the level or the user dies the pause/restart dialog appears (Scene2D). The problem is that I still have moving sprites in the background and it would make the game look not so good if I would stop processing those sprite movements. BUT, this slows down the game considerably(from 60fps to 40f/45f) when in pause mode and I also render an **ADMOB banner ad**.

Is there any chance I can optimize ADMOB ? or should ADMOB not be used when moving sprites are on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment right now because I don't have enough reputation, but using a profiler, like [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) would be very helpful and could show you exactly what is going wrong. Sorry for having to submit this as an answer, I would comment but I can't!